# Basic Fabric.js Image Selection with Mask

Tags: javascript, image, html5-canvas, fabricjs, html2canvas

I have a unique (but hopefully simple) issue to fix with Fabric.js to fix.

I have this very simple example below:
[image]

I have

- 2 Images
- Both have an `absolutePositioned` mask via `clipPath` property on the `fabric.Image` instance

My issue is:
**I want the image to only be selectable (and hoverable) whenever the selection happens within the bounds of the mask, not anywhere on image (even outside of the bounds of its mask).**

This image shows the mouse hovering over the red door picture (even though the mouse is outside of the mask bounds, but not outside the image bounds:[image]

Here's a code snippet of the door image snippet:

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(url1, function(img){
  canvas.add(img.set({
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    clipPath: rect1,
    hasControls: false,
  }));
  img.on('mouseover', () => {
    const filter = new fabric.Image.filters.BlendColor({
      color: 'white',
      alpha: 0.7,
      mode: 'tint'
    })
    img.filters.push(filter)
    img.applyFilters()
    canvas.renderAll()
  })
  img.on('mouseout', () => {
    img.filters.pop()
    img.applyFilters()
    canvas.renderAll()
  })
}, {crossOrigin: "Anonymous"});
```

---

[**JS Fiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/qarthandjs/ztreqy78/8/) showing the current behavior that I'm trying to change.

Comment: Remember that SO have code snippets, so instead of using an external solution, it would be nice if you could use that instead. There are fewer risks that the snippet won't work in the future, and on the other hand, is very practical to be able to copy your code to the answer directly.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to listen to the mouse event in the canvas and toggle the `activeObject` based on the mouse position:

```
canvas.observe('mouse:move', function(options) {
  const pos = canvas.getPointer(options.e);
  if (!imageRight || !imageLeft) return
  if (pos.x > 200) {
    activeImage = imageRight
  } else {
    activeImage = imageLeft
  }
  const activeObj = canvas.getActiveObject();
  if (activeImage !== activeObj) {
    canvas.setActiveObject(activeImage);
    canvas.renderAll()
  }
});
```

This is a very simplified way to detect if the mouse is over the image. It checks if the `x > 200` since that is where the line between both images is positioned. This could be improved to be more accurate, but it works just to illustrate the idea.

```js
var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

const url1 = 'https://picsum.photos/300/200'
const url2 = 'https://picsum.photos/320'

let imageRight
let imageLeft
let activeImage

canvas.observe('mouse:move', function(options) {
  const pos = canvas.getPointer(options.e);
  if (!imageRight || !imageLeft) return
  if (pos.x > 200) {
    activeImage = imageRight
  } else {
    activeImage = imageLeft
  }
  const activeObj = canvas.getActiveObject();
  if (activeImage !== activeObj) {
    canvas.setActiveObject(activeImage);
    canvas.renderAll()
  }
});

const baseProps = {
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  top: 0,
  fill: '#000',
  absolutePositioned: true,
  hasControls: false,
  evented: false,
  selectable: false
}

const rect1 = new fabric.Rect({
  ...baseProps,
  left: 0,
})

const rect2 = new fabric.Rect({
  ...baseProps,
  left: 200,
})

canvas.add(rect1)
canvas.add(rect2)

fabric.Image.fromURL(url2, function(img) {
  imageRight = img
  canvas.add(img.set({
    left: 200,
    top: 0,
    clipPath: rect2,
    hasControls: false
  }))
}, {
  crossOrigin: "Anonymouse"
})

fabric.Image.fromURL(url1, function(img) {
  imageLeft = img
  canvas.add(img.set({
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    clipPath: rect1,
    hasControls: false,
  }));
}, {
  crossOrigin: "Anonymous"
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 2px red solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.6.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="420" height="220"></canvas>
```